# BPM runs even after deleting it (Epicor)

Tags: epicorerp, epicor, epicor10

I have removed a BPM which has been in Epicor for some time. I initially disabled it to stop it from executing, however, the BPM still executes. My next approach was deleting the BPM, but still, the BPM runs even after deleting it. 
Could someone shed some light on how to fix this issue?
My epicor version is epicor 10

Comment: Just a note on versions, "epicor 10" is not descriptive. Epicor ERP 10.0.600 was a few years back, and there have been lots of versions since. Ignoring the frequent cadence releases 10.2.300 is the latest version at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be absolutely sure that the BPM you are deleting is the correct one I'd add an email action (just email yourself) to the BPM and run it through once.

You may also want to recompile your BPMs just to check that the latest exists on the server. Also you don't mention if you have multiple app servers or possibly a separate task server.

In my experience, this usually happens because I've deleted or disabled the wrong BPM,